# how to use map function in r to find the range and quantile

Tags: r, plot, range, tidyverse, map-function

I first simulated 500 samples of size 55 in the normal distribution.

```
samples <- replicate(500, rnorm(55,mean=50, sd=10), simplify = FALSE)
```

1) For each sample, I want the mean, median, range, and third quartile. Then I need to store these together in a data frame.

This is what I have. I am not sure about the range or the quantile. I tried sapply and lapply but not sure how they work.

```
stats <- data.frame(
means = map_dbl(samples,mean),
medians = map_dbl(samples,median),
sd= map_dbl(samples,sd),

range= map_int(samples, max-min),
third_quantile=sapply(samples,quantile,type=3)
)
```

2) Then plot the sampling distribution (histogram) of the means.
I try to plot but I don't get how to get the mean

```
stats <- gather(stats, key = "Trials", value = "Mean")

ggplot(stats,aes(x=Trials))+geom_histogram()
```

3) Then I want to plot the other three statistics in (three separate graphs) of a single plotting window.

I know I need to use something like gather and facet_wrap, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. All it is needed is to define *anonymous functions* wherever there are errors.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible

samples <- replicate(500, rnorm(55,mean=50, sd=10), simplify = FALSE)
str(samples)

stats <- data.frame(
  means = map_dbl(samples, mean),
  medians = map_dbl(samples, median),
  sd = map_dbl(samples, sd),
  range = map_dbl(samples, function(x) diff(range(x))),
  third_quantile = map_dbl(samples, function(x) quantile(x, probs = 3/4, type = 3))
)

str(stats)
#'data.frame':  500 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ means         : num  49.8 51.5 52.2 50.2 51.6 ...
# $ medians       : num  51.5 51.7 51 51.1 50.5 ...
# $ sd            : num  9.55 7.81 11.43 8.97 10.75 ...
# $ range         : num  38.5 37.2 54 36.7 60.2 ...
# $ third_quantile: num  57.7 56.2 58.8 55.6 57 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map_dbl` functions you're using are definitely nice, but if you're trying to get a data frame in the end anyway, you might have an easier time converting the list into a data frame at the beginning, then taking advantage of some `dplyr` functions.

I'm first mapping over the list, creating tibbles, and binding it together with an added ID. The conversion creates a column `value` of the sample values. `summarise_at` lets you take a list of functions—supplying names in the list sets the names in the resultant data frame. You can use `purrr`'s `~.` notation to define these functions inline where needed. Cuts down on the number of times you have to `map_dbl` and so on.

```r
library(tidyverse)
stats <- samples %>%
  map_dfr(as_tibble, .id = "sample") %>%
  group_by(sample) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(value), 
               .funs = list(mean = mean, median = median, sd = sd,
                            range = ~(max(.) - min(.)),
                            third_quartile = ~quantile(., probs = 0.75)))

head(stats)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   sample  mean median    sd range third_quartile
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 1       45.0   44.4  8.71  47.6           48.6
#> 2 10      51.0   52.0  9.55  49.3           56.2
#> 3 100     51.6   52.2 10.4   60.7           58.1
#> 4 101     51.6   51.1  9.92  37.6           57.2
#> 5 102     49.1   48.2  9.65  39.8           57.0
#> 6 103     52.2   51.3 10.1   47.4           58.5
```

Next, in your code you `gather`ed the data—which is often the solution folks need on SO—but if you're only trying to show the mean column, you can work with it as is.

```r
ggplot(stats, aes(x = mean)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image]